# What are some software packages that allow visualization of molecules in 3D?

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

Could anyone suggest a good application or a software that helps visualise molecular structures in 3d? 
I have tried a few applications like King Draw and molecular constructor but I want to know if there are better ones out there.

Comment: Avogadro is free and is compatible with almost any standard chemical format, plus it has some force fields for structure optimization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make 3d molecular graphics similar to those shown on Wikipedia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/74546); [Freely available software for generating 3D coordinates of molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119886).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples are: MOLDEN, Avogadro, JMol and VMD.
But there is a very thorough list (along with comparisons) here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_molecular_graphics_systems.